# macro to choose sheet, column, and rows to filter based on cell criteria

Tags: excel, filter, macros

New to Excel macros, trying to get something figured out for my work!  Any help is **greatly** appreciated!

I'm trying to make a macro that will choose the **sheet**, the **column**, *and* the **row** when filtering, all based on cell criteria.

So in Sheet1, if someone types in the sheet name "Sheet6" in Cell A1, column header "col_B" into Cell A2, and the filter criteria "banks" into Cell A3, then the macro will look in "Sheet6", find the column with the header "col_B" and filter all rows with the text "banks".  Is this possible?

Thank you ahead of time for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to adapt this:

```
Sub FeedingTheVampire()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, cHead As String, crit As String
    Dim rcol As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set sh = Sheets(CStr(.Range("A1")))
        cHead = .Range("A2")
        crit = .Range("A3")
    End With

    Set rcol = sh.Range("1:1").Find(What:=cHead, After:=sh.Range("A1")).EntireColumn
    rcol.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=crit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will check that out and see what I can do!

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.  I noticed the sub name, and I hope in the next couple months as I keep learning how to do this stuff, that I can contribute and help to at least be a helpful vampire who helps feed everyone else as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just got very close using code from another workbook.  I don't fully understand the other code, as I got some of it off of google searches.  The only thing this code doesn't do is reference the column (that R1 variable is supposed to, but I'm not sure how to put it in).  A lot of it looks similar to the post from Gary's Student.  And I'm sure there is information in that to make this work.  So, thank you again Gary's Student!

Sub Filter_Stuff()

Dim r As Range,
 Dim strName As String,
 Dim R1 As String,
 Dim s2 As Worksheet, s1 As Worksheet, sA As Worksheet

```
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")


strName = Range("C5")
Set sA = Sheets(strName)

R1 = s2.Range("C6")

Set r = sA.Range("1:1").Find(What:=s2.Range("C6").Value, After:=sA.Range("A1"))

r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=s2.Range("C7").Value
```

End Sub

Comment: Gary's Student's post figured it out.  Ignore this one.  Thanks!